# How do you compile example00 from the cURLpp github repo?

Tags: curlpp

I installed cURLpp, and I am trying to compile example00.cpp from their GitHub repo. But, when I run `g++ example00.cpp -o example00` I get this output:

> /tmp/cc619KAL.o: In function `main':
>   example00.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to`curlpp::Cleanup::Cleanup()'
>   example00.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `curlpp::Easy::Easy()'
>   example00.cpp:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to`curlpp::Easy::perform()'
>   example00.cpp:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to `curlpp::Easy::~Easy()'
>   example00.cpp:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to`curlpp::Cleanup::~Cleanup()'
>   example00.cpp:(.text+0xf5): undefined reference to `curlpp::Easy::~Easy()'
>   example00.cpp:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to`curlpp::Cleanup::~Cleanup()'
>   /tmp/cc619KAL.o:(.gcc_except_table+0x48): undefined reference to `typeinfo for curlpp::LogicError'
>   /tmp/cc619KAL.o:(.gcc_except_table+0x4c): undefined reference to`typeinfo for curlpp::RuntimeError'
>   /tmp/cc619KAL.o: In function `curlpp::Option<std::string>::~Option()':
>   example00.cpp:(.text._ZN6curlpp6OptionISsED2Ev[_ZN6curlpp6OptionISsED5Ev]+0x49): undefined reference to`curlpp::OptionBase::~OptionBase()'
>   example00.cpp:(.text._ZN6curlpp6OptionISsED2Ev[_ZN6curlpp6OptionISsED5Ev]+0x6f): undefined reference to `curlpp::OptionBase::~OptionBase()'
>   /tmp/cc619KAL.o: In function`curlpp::Option::Option(CURLoption, std::string const&)':
>   example00.cpp:(.text._ZN6curlpp6OptionISsEC2E10CURLoptionRKSs[_ZN6curlpp6OptionISsEC5E10CURLoptionRKSs]+0x21): undefined reference to `curlpp::OptionBase::OptionBase(CURLoption)'
>   example00.cpp:(.text._ZN6curlpp6OptionISsEC2E10CURLoptionRKSs[_ZN6curlpp6OptionISsEC5E10CURLoptionRKSs]+0x5c): undefined reference to`curlpp::OptionBase::~OptionBase()'
>   /tmp/cc619KAL.o:(.rodata._ZTVN6curlpp11OptionTraitISsL10CURLoption10002EEE[_ZTVN6curlpp11OptionTraitISsL10CURLoption10002EEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `curlpp::OptionBase::operator<(curlpp::OptionBase const&) const'
>   /tmp/cc619KAL.o:(.rodata._ZTVN6curlpp6OptionISsEE[_ZTVN6curlpp6OptionISsEE]+0x20): undefined reference to`curlpp::OptionBase::operator<(curlpp::OptionBase const&) const'
>   /tmp/cc619KAL.o:(.rodata._ZTIN6curlpp6OptionISsEE[_ZTIN6curlpp6OptionISsEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for curlpp::OptionBase'
>   /tmp/cc619KAL.o: In function`curlpp::UnsetOption::~UnsetOption()':
>   example00.cpp:(.text._ZN6curlpp11UnsetOptionD2Ev[_ZN6curlpp11UnsetOptionD5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `curlpp::RuntimeError::~RuntimeError()'
>   /tmp/cc619KAL.o: In function`curlpp::Option::updateMeToOption(curlpp::OptionBase const&)':
>   example00.cpp:(.text._ZN6curlpp6OptionISsE16updateMeToOptionERKNS_10OptionBaseE[_ZN6curlpp6OptionISsE16updateMeToOptionERKNS_10OptionBaseE]+0x30): undefined reference to `typeinfo for curlpp::OptionBase'
>   example00.cpp:(.text._ZN6curlpp6OptionISsE16updateMeToOptionERKNS_10OptionBaseE[_ZN6curlpp6OptionISsE16updateMeToOptionERKNS_10OptionBaseE]+0x5d): undefined reference to`curlpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption(char const*)'
>   /tmp/cc619KAL.o: In function `curlpp::OptionTrait<std::string, (CURLoption)10002>::updateHandleToMe(curlpp::internal::CurlHandle*) const':
>   example00.cpp:(.text._ZNK6curlpp11OptionTraitISsL10CURLoption10002EE16updateHandleToMeEPNS_8internal10CurlHandleE[_ZNK6curlpp11OptionTraitISsL10CURLoption10002EE16updateHandleToMeEPNS_8internal10CurlHandleE]+0x59): undefined reference to`curlpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption(std::string const&)'
>   /tmp/cc619KAL.o: In function `curlpp::Option<std::string>::getValue() const':
>   example00.cpp:(.text._ZNK6curlpp6OptionISsE8getValueEv[_ZNK6curlpp6OptionISsE8getValueEv]+0x59): undefined reference to`curlpp::UnsetOption::UnsetOption(std::string const&)'
>   /tmp/cc619KAL.o: In function `void curlpp::internal::CurlHandle::option<void*>(CURLoption, void*)':
>   example00.cpp:(.text._ZN6curlpp8internal10CurlHandle6optionIPvEEv10CURLoptionT_[_ZN6curlpp8internal10CurlHandle6optionIPvEEv10CURLoptionT_]+0x2d): undefined reference to`curl_easy_setopt'
>   example00.cpp:(.text.*ZN6curlpp8internal10CurlHandle6optionIPvEEv10CURLoptionT*[*ZN6curlpp8internal10CurlHandle6optionIPvEEv10CURLoptionT*]+0x45): undefined reference to `curlpp::libcurlRuntimeAssert(char const*, CURLcode)'
>   /tmp/cc619KAL.o:(.rodata._ZTIN6curlpp11UnsetOptionE[_ZTIN6curlpp11UnsetOptionE]+0x10): undefined reference to`typeinfo for curlpp::RuntimeError'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TheWatcher_,  you need to link in both curlpp and curl (adding in `-lcurlpp` and `-lcurl` to your linker line). For a more complete step-by-step, here is what you need to do.

1. Clone the latest curlpp from github.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp.git
   ```
2. Go into the git directory and prepare it for compilation

   ```
   cd curlpp
   ./autogen.sh
   ./configure
   ```
3. Now, lets compile the library as well as all of the examples

   ```
   make
   ```

**In Summary:** Once the library has been built, cd into the examples directory and run the following (pulled from make) for any of the examples (replacing the 00 with the example number required):

```
cd examples
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include/curlpp  -I../include   -g  -W -Wall -Werror    -I/usr/local/include -MT example00.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/example00.Tpo -c -o example00.o example00.cpp
mv -f .deps/example00.Tpo .deps/example00.Po
/bin/sh ../libtool --silent  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g  -W -Wall -Werror -I/usr/local/include -L../src/curlpp/ -lcurlpp -static -o example00 example00.o -lstdc++ -lcurl
```